# Do Z translations stack for views within viewgroups that also have a Z translation?

Tags: android, android-layout

Let's say you have a view within a constraint layout. If you were to give the constraint layout a -40 z translation and the view a 5 z translation, would the view's z value be 5 or -35? And would it then be above or behind a sibling view to the constraint layout with a 0 z translation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They don't stack. The views keep whatever their personal z translation is. Even if it's 0, they don't inherit their parent Z.